# how to config SSRS 2005 email setting with google apps

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs, google-app-engine

My Company recently switches email service to google apps (asp.google.com). all the current subscriptions in SSRS2005 are configured to MS exchange server and no longer workable. Do someone knows how to configure subscriptions to google apps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. This [msdn walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345234%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) should have everything you need to accomplish what you want to do on the SSRS 2005 side.  Pay attention to the section on **setting up for remote smtp**.  Especially the part about setting `SendUsing` to 2.
2. This [google guide](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176600) provides the steps to configure things on their end.

The [setup for SSRS 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) isn't much different.

Comment: It only works with internal email address. External is unworkable.